# Moving from A(x,y) to B(x1,y1) with constant speed?

Tags: game-mechanics, movement

I currently have something like:

```
float deltaX = point0.getX() - point1.getX();
float deltaY = point0.getY() - point1.getY();
```

And every 0.01 seconds I refresh my objects position like this:

```
object.setPosition(object.getX()-deltaX/100,object.getY()-deltaY/100);
```

So this moves my object from point0 to point1 in 1 second. What I need is having the 2 points, to be able to move the object from point0 ,facing(in the direction of) point1 with a constant speed. Thus, when I have a point closer to my initial point the object will move towards it with the same speed it does if I would have a farther point.
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23430/get-points-on-a-line-between-two-points

I would post the same answer that i gave to the other question. But this would be shameless of my part.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'll use some linear algebra structures since it's easier to describe the operations that way. In case you don't know how to implement these vector operations I'll give a quick explanation at the end.

So let's say you start with these values: `start`and `end` mark the end points of the movement, `speed` is how many pixels it should move by second, and `elapsed` is the rate at which you'll update your object's position (some engines already provide that value for you):

```cs
Vector2 start = new Vector2(x1, y2);
Vector2 end = new Vector2(x2, y2);
float speed = 100;
float elapsed = 0.01f;
```

The first thing you'll want to calculate is the distance between both points, and a normalized vector containing the direction from start to end. Also, you should "snap" the object position to the `start` point. This step is done only once, at the beginning:

```
float distance = Vector2.Distance(start, end);
Vector2 direction = Vector2.Normalize(end - start);
object.Position = start;
moving = true;
```

Then on your update method, you move the object by adding a multiplication of `direction`, `speed` and `elapsed` to its position. After that, to check if the movement is over, you see if the distance between the start point and the object's current position is *greater* than the initial distance you calculated. If that's true, we snap the object's position to the end point, and stop moving the object:

```
if(moving == true)
{
    object.Position += direction * speed * elapsed;
    if(Vector2.Distance(start, object.Position) >= distance)
    {
        object.Position = end;
        moving = false;
    }
}
```

---

**Quick Vector Operations Reference**

*Representation*

```
Vector2 A = float aX, aY;
```

*Sum / Subtract*

```
A+B = a.x + b.x; a.y + b.y;
A-B = a.x - b.x; a.y - b.y;
```

*Multiply by Scalar (float)*

```
A*float = a.x*float; a.y*float;
```

*Length / Distance*

```
length(A) = sqrt(a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y)
distance(A,B) = length(B-A)
```

*Normalize*

```
normalize(A) = a.X/length(A); a.Y/length(A);
```

That should be enough to convert the above code into regular operations if you don't have a `Vector` class available to you.

---

**Example of Conversion**

```
// Your Variables
float startX, startY, endX, endY;
float speed = 100;
float elapsed = 0.01f;

// On starting movement
float distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endX-startX,2)+Math.pow(endY-startY,2));
float directionX = (endX-startX) / distance;
float directionY = (endY-startY) / distance;
object.X = startX;
object.Y = startY;
moving = true;

// On update
if(moving == true)
{
    object.X += directionX * speed * elapsed;
    object.Y += directionY * speed * elapsed;
    if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(object.X-startX,2)+Math.pow(object.Y-startY,2)) >= distance)
    {
        object.X = endX;
        object.Y = endY;
        moving = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fofole That's why I gave the explanation on vectors at the end. The answer was supposed to be generic. If you don't have a Vector class, then use two separate floats. For instance `Vector2 start;` becomes `float startX, startY;`. And you can easily calculate the distance manually, like I explain at the end. I.e. `float dX = bX - aX; float dY = bY - aY; float distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);`.

Comment: @Fafole Check the edit, I added an example. Not sure if I missed something though.

Comment: One small thing to add is that you could use the squared distance to do the check in order to save an a square root op, which should help performance quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Copied and pasted from my answer to: [Get points on a line between two points](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23430/get-points-on-a-line-between-two-points)

In Pseudocode:

```
speed_per_tick = 0.05 //constant speed you want the object to move at
delta_x = x_goal - x_current
delta_y = y_goal - y_current
goal_dist = sqrt( (delta_x * delta_x) + (delta_y * delta_y) )
if (dist > speed_per_tick)
{
    ratio = speed_per_tick / goal_dist
    x_move = ratio * delta_x  
    y_move = ratio * delta_y
    new_x_pos = x_move + x_current  
    new_y_pos = y_move + y_current
}
else
{
    new_x_pos = x_goal 
    new_y_pos = y_goal
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a Vector and normalize it. Warning, some pseudo-code with wrong numbers ahead:

```
Vector = new Vector(point0.getX() - point1.getX(), point0.getY() - point1.getY());
```

This will give you a Vector like:

```
25.96; 85.41
```

[Now normalize the vector, and you'll receive this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector):

```
0.12; 0.75
```

From here it's the same movement as with your delta.